# Get nth element from page using CSS selector in selenium

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

Thanks in advance!

I want to know if there is any way in CSS selector in which we can find nth element in page?

I believe in xpath if there multiple element which satisfies an xpath we can get nth element using below syntax:
//input[2]                     ' Select 2nd Input

Please note I am not looking for nth-child(n) or nth-of-type(n) which selects child element of parent.

Comment: You can use `find_elements...()` (Python syntax) instead of `find_element...()`. You'll be able to find second input as `find_elements_by_css_selector('input')[1]`

Comment: If you want a more accurate answer -- give us HTML code/page.

Answer (score 0):

> Please note I am not looking for nth-child(n) or nth-of-type(n) which selects child element of parent.

That is how you locate the Nth element in CSS locators. If your looking for the Nth root element, you can use html or body as parent elements. `By.CssLocator("body:nth(2)")`

That seems like a strange solution though. Can you post more information describing your requirements? There may be a better way of locating the element than using a CSS locator. Of course if you have the ability to modify the source, than this could easily be fixed by design. I recommend using `data-*` attributes.